# Upgrade to highcharts 3.0 results in bar graph distortion

Tags: highcharts

I just upgraded to highcharts 3.0 and seem to have come accross an issue with one of my existing graphs that was working correctly before the upgrade but now is somewhat broken.

Sometimes the graph displays correctly sometimes but it gets distroted on some occasions. Please see below for examples, any help would be greatly appriciated.

The chart data is dynamically written with setData.

working: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpHEy.png

Not working: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzjMh.png

half way:i.imgur.com/aXlACKZ.png

Comment: Could you recreate your example in jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not easily, it's pretty intertwined with some php code, ajax etc. All the data is written using the modifyer commands. I just wondered if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Sebastian and everyone at highcharts, I just upgraded to the latest version (3.0.1) and it appears as though this issue has been resolved. :D

http://www.highcharts.com/download